# Multiple conditions using an AND if Statement, javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, multiple-conditions

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this **if** statement?

If I use either of the two main conditions on their own the statement works fine but when I add that middle **&& statement**, it stops working. I've searched online and can't see what's wrong.

**P.S**. I can even change that middle **&&** to a **||** statement and it works as well. I'm so confused.

```
if ((containerId.id == "LineOne" && dropLoc == "dropLocation1.1") && (containerId.id == "LineTwo" && dropLoc == "dropLocation2.2"))
        {
            alert("finished");
            cdpause();      
        }
```

Comment: changing that middle `&&` to a `||` is the solution

Comment: AND means AND. containerId.id cannot be "LineOne" and "LineTwo" at the same time.

Comment: I fifgured it out... My main issue is i'm an idiot... but besides that I have the same variables containerId, and dropLoc being used twice... I'm trying to use an array now... thanks

Answer (score 4):

> I've searched online and can't see what's wrong.
>
> I can even change that middle && to a || statement and it works as well

Because `containerId.id` can't be `LineOne` and `LineTwo` at the same time.

Similarly, `dropLoc` can't have two values at the same time.

But it can have one of the two values, so replace `&&` with `||`.

```
   if ((containerId.id == "LineOne" && dropLoc == "dropLocation1.1") || 
       (containerId.id == "LineTwo" && dropLoc == "dropLocation2.2"))
   {
        alert("finished");
        cdpause();      
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combinte the two checks with an OR, because, you can not have two different values at the same time.

Beside that, you need no brackets, because of the [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) of [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) over [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()).

```
if (
    containerId.id == "LineOne" && dropLoc == "dropLocation1.1" ||
    containerId.id == "LineTwo" && dropLoc == "dropLocation2.2"
) {
    alert("finished");
    cdpause();      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Satpal said

```
 if(containerId.id == "LineOne" && dropLoc == "dropLocation1.1") || (containerId.id == "LineTwo" && dropLoc == "dropLocation2.2")
```

Answer (score 0):

You already had the correct solution, you should have a *||* (or) instead of a *&&* (and) in the middle.

It's basic boolean logic: you have two expressions with "and", and you want to execute your code if either of those expressions are true, so you join those expressions with "or".

"If the name is John and it's Monday OR if the name is Jane and it's Tuesday , then remind them to shop for groceries." => on Monday, it's John's turn to go shopping, on Tuesday, it is Jane's.